# Using a PHP input field to fill another

Tags: javascript, php, input

I'm trying to fill the field 'course number' with a string as soon as the user selects the Course he wants form the 'select' input type.

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work.

---

// Part of My Code Below ...

```
    <strong style="border:double; margin-right: 34px; border-color:#cc0000;"> Course Name: </strong>
    <select style="margin-bottom: 20px" name="course_name" id="courseName">
        <option selected> -Select Course- </option>
        <option value="C++" name="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="DataBase" name="DataBase"> DataBase </option>
        <option value="DataStructure" name="DataStructure">DataStructure</option>
        <option value="JAVA" name="Java"> JAVA </option>
        <option value="WEB" name="Web" > WEB </option>
    </select> <br>

    <strong>    <label style="border:double; border-color:#cc0000;"> Course Number:     </strong>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var courseNumber = document.getElementById('courseName').value;
            switch(courseNumber){
                case: 'C++'
                    courseNumber = "151001100"
                    break;
                case: 'DataBase'
                    courseNumber = '151002240';
                    break;
                case: 'DataStructure'
                    courseNumber = '151001240';
                    break;
                case: 'Java'
                    courseNumber = '151001110';
                    break;
                case: 'Web'
                    courseNumber = '151002310';
                    break;
            }
        </script>

        <input type="text" name="course_num" id="courseNum" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 
        12px" >
    </label> <br>
```

Comment: Your approach makes it look like your internal modal of how variables work is off. You also need to move the code into an `onchange` event listener.

Comment: One reason is because you are already getting the value of `x` during page load, which equals to blank/null. Also, you aren't even using `x`

Comment: Make sure that your DOM is loaded before running JavaScript, then use a change Event.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8b7k9tf5/ (used a table for layout, used `<span>` to display number since it's not supposed to be edited, used array to get from selection to number)+

Comment: @CarlBinalla i have tried to print the value of the variable (x) and it is indeed NULL, i have no idea why,  Also how do i use it so it will be the value for the 'courseNum' in the next Field

Comment: At face value, what you need is `document.getElementById("courseNum").value = x;` after the switch statement. You still need to wrap all that in `onchange` though. It also makes the code much more readable if you use `var courseName ...`, then change a new var called `courseNum` in your switch block.

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean by wrapping all the code in onchange ?

Comment: The code that checks the selected course and inserts the number has to run whenever the selection changes. Which means you have to move it inside a function, then run the function as the select element's `onchange` event fires. See the fiddle I linked that does exactly that. With your version, all that code runs when the page is loaded, then never again. Changing the selection has no effect.